# Ob man am Mittag zu Mittag isst?

Tags: phrase

Auf Deutsch heißt es: *zu Mittag essen*.

Meine Frage ist, ob man bei genauerer Zeitangabe schreiben bzw. sagen darf: ***am Mittag** zu Mittag essen*. Z.B. "Wir essen am Mittag zu Mittag." (Englisch: "We eat lunch at midday.")

Das kommt mir wegen der Verdoppelung von *Mittag* eher komisch vor; da ich aber Deutsch als Fremdsprache gelernt habe und bisher nur wenig Zeit im deutschsprachigen Raum habe verbringen können, traue ich meinem Sprachgefühl nicht gänzlich, besonders wo es um die Alltagssprache geht, weil ich meistens mit der geschriebenen (literarischen/philosophischen) Sprache zu tun habe. Deshalb bitte ich um eine Erklärung, d.h. ob das *überhaupt* geht (z.B. umgangssprachlich / salopp) oder, wenn gar nicht, *warum* nicht (z.B. weil *am Mittag* und *zu Mittag* gleichbedeutend sind) und was in dem Fall möglich wäre (ich schätze mal: "Wir essen um 12 zu Mittag.").

Danke im Voraus!

Comment: Es geht, aber niemand würde es (außer als Stilmittel) verwenden. "Wir essen um 12 zu Mittag." ist üblich.

Comment: Ich halte es für falsch, da für mich die Ausdrücke *zu Mittag* und *zum Mittag* wegen der Präposition *zu* ausdrücklich die *Mittagszeit* bezeichnen, und nicht das *Mittagessen*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wie fast immer wenn es um Alltagssprache geht, sind regionale Unterschiede zu beachten. Und wie immer bei solchen Fragen kann ich nur über die Gegebenheiten im Osten Österreichs berichten, ohne genau zu wissen, wie alltäglich diese Ausprägung der Alltagssprache in anderen Regionen ist.

Im Osten Österreichs ist die Formulierung aus der Frage wenig gebräuchlich. Gebräuchlich sind diese Formulierungen:

> »Was hast du heute zu Mittag gemacht?« - »Na was schon? Ich habe Mittag gegessen.«

> »Du isst jetzt eine Wurstsemmel?« - »Ja, ich habe sonst nichts mit, das ist mein Mittagessen.«

> Telefonat im Homeoffice: »Sorry, du rufst gerade zu einer ungünstigen Zeit an, ich bin gerade beim Mittagessen.«

> »Mama, wann gibt's endlich das Mittagessen?« - »Das Mittagessen gibt es zu Mittag. Jetzt ist es erst halb elf.«

> »Was gibt es heute zu Mittag zum Essen?« = »Was gibt es heute als Mittagessen?«

Ein Satz mit der Bedeutung wie er in der Frage formuliert war, würde ungefähr so lauten:

> »Wir essen zu Mittag das Mittagessen.«

Denn *»zu Mittag«* meint immer die Zeit in der Mitte des Tages, aber nie eine Speise. Die Speise ist *»das Mittagessen«,* und der Verzehr derselben umschreibt man ohne vorangestellten Artikel mit *»Mittag essen«.*

Die Gefüge *»zum Mittag«* und *»am Mittag«* existieren im Osten Österreichs nicht.

Anstatt *»Wir essen um 12 Uhr zu Mittag«* sagt man hier *»Mittagessen gibt's um 12 Uhr«.* Denn sowohl *»12 Uhr«* als auch *»zu Mittag«* sind im Osten Österreichs reine Zeitangaben.

Comment: Ist es in OÖ auch üblich, statt "... das ist mein Mittagessen" nur "...das ist mein Mittag" zu sagen? Also das "Mittagessen" mit "Mittag" abgekürzt wird?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Ich kenne keine Oberösterreicher persönlich und bin nur selten in Oberösterreich, daher kann ich diese Frage nicht mit Gewissheit beantworten. Ich weiß aus demselben Grund auch nicht, wie das in Bayern gehandhabt wird.

Comment: oh, sorry, falsche Abkürzung: sollte "Osten Österreichs" werden, weil das hier die Referenz war. Habe keine Sekunde an übliche Abkürzungen gedacht. Also tut mir leid, Frage bitte auf "Ost-Österreich" beziehen, danke :)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Auf den Osten Österreichs bezogen kann ich diese Frage natürlich beantworten. Die Antwort lautet: Nein. »Das ist mein Mittag« sagt hier bei uns niemand.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Im Gegensatz zu Ost-Deutschland, oder auch Ost-Steiermark ist Ost-Österreich keine irgendwie näher definierte Region. Daher habe ich auch vom »Osten Österreichs« gesprochen. OÖ ist die gängige Abkürzung für das Bundesland Oberösterreich (NÖ = Niederösterreich, St = Steiermark, alle anderen Bundesländer werden mit dem 1. Buchstaben abgekürzt). »OÖ« und die anderen Abkürzungen sind in Österreich so bekannt und eindeutig besetzt wie »NRW« in Deutschland.

Comment: "Denn »zu Mittag« meint immer die Zeit in der Mitte des Tages, aber nie eine Speise." Das ist dort, wo ich sprachlich sozialisiert wurde (Sachsen) anders. Dort sagt man durchaus: _Was gibt's zu(m) Mittag?_ und meint damit, "welche Speise?"

Answer (score 2):

Prinzipiell ist es erstmal ein grammatikalisch korrekter Satz. Das heißt, jetzt muss noch überlegt werden, ob er auch sinnig ist.

Üblicherweise wird das Frühstück als erste Mahlzeit, das Mittagessen als zweite Mahlzeit und das Abendessen als dritte Mahlzeit des Tages erachtet. Dies lässt dann auch zu, am Mittag oder erst am Abend zu frühstücken, um damit auszudrücken, dass dies die erste Mahlzeit ist. Für Leute mit unkonventionellem Schlafrhythmus, kann es also durchaus Sinn machen, zu betonen, dass man mittags zu Mittag isst (im Gegensatz zu mittags frühstücken).

Comment: *Mittags zu Mittag* ist für mich ein Pleonasmus, da *zu Mittag* für mich die *Mittagszeit*, also eben *mittags* bezeichnet.

Answer (score 0):

Es ist nicht falsch, aber wohl eine tautologie, da das Mittagessen definitionsgemäss immer mittags erfolgt.

Die Zeitangabe „Mittag“ bezeichnet nämlich nicht nur 12:00, sondern auch die „Zeit um die Mitte des Tages (gegen und nach 12 Uhr)“ [Siehe Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mittag_Pause_Uhrzeit_Sueden)

Die Ausdrücke „zu Mittag essen“ wie auch „Mittag“ (ugs.) für das Mittagessen sind gemäss Duden korrekt, aber wahrscheinlich regional unterschiedlich stark in Verwendung. Z.B. in der Schweiz würde niemand bei „zu Mittag essen“ komisch schauen, da man auf Schweizerdeutsch vom „Zmittag“ spricht.